# Comparing means between 3 different groups across time (given that the 3 groups are defined by 2 factors)

Tags: anova, experiment-design, biostatistics

I have 3 different experimental groups:

1) Wild-type, control
2) Transgenic, control
3) Transgenic, Drug-treated

Therefore, my groups are defined based on two factors: genotype and drug treatment

These animals were tested at 2 different points: December and January.

What is the appropriate statistical analysis that I should use?

Comment: Please indicate the objective you have . Also describe data-type. All three do not seem to be experimental groups.

Comment: Please specify if all of these groups are related or you are trying to get mean difference between each individual group and its control